# Host "localhost"overwrites "localhost"in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, vue.js

I`m trying to run a vue dashboard in docker container and a service on my local machine. both are binded to "localhost:80". When running both the dashboard and the service in docer, everything works fine, but when running the dashboard in docker and the second service on host machine, the host machine somehow overwrites the access to the docker localhost. so the expected behaviour:
- http://localhost -> should load the dashboard
- http://localhost/graphql -> should load the api for graphql from the second service

so these are working when both running in docker, but not working when one is in docker and the second one running on hist.
Any idea how to solve the issue? The reason why I need to have the second service running on host is that I can debug and code quicker instead of building image after each code change and updating the stack.

Thanks, Zoli.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` inside docker refers to the docker container itself. You can't access the actual host from inside docker with that.

However, your actual host has an IP address in the docker network. You can access your actual host using that IP. You can get it by doing `ifconfig`. Look for a `docker` interface. In my machine the actual host has the IP `172.17.0.1`

Comment: that is fine, I already has the connection from docker to the host. the problem is that by default when the "dashboard"is not running, http://localhost gives me {status: "up"} which is fine. once I start the "dashboard"in docker and the second service on host, it should give me the "dashboard"on http://loclahost, but instead it still gives the  {status: "up"}, which is not what I want

Comment: another info to this: for development purpose the dashboard should run in docker and the service on host, but the host overwrites "lcoalhost" and I can`t access the "dashboard" on host from docker like when both are running in docker

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, on host I had to change the port and it started to work. so when both services are running in docker, the port 80 can be assigned to 2 containers and will be resolved correctly. but when one is running it from docker and another on host, it will not work. that is my explanation to this, maybe someone can give a better explanation, but the problem is solved now. thanks.